# "Hands-Free AG Audio" outputs audio but "stereo" doesn't

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset

I have a Sennheiser HD 250BT wireless headset. When I connect it to Windows 10 through bluetooth, it shows connected as two different devinces: "Hands-Free AG Audio" device and "stereo" device.

When I output sound to the HF AG Audio device, I get audio normally, but when I try to output it to the stereo device, I get just silence. Any ideias about this?

Also, device manager displays two unknown, driveless devices: Bluetooth Peripheral Device and GAIA. Are those related to the problem? Where can I find drivers for them?

Comment: You already have the appropriate drivers installed. They are built-into Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound no, device manager reports them as having no drivers. I believe them to be unrelated, though.